# Word add-in not appearing in Office store

Tags: office-js, word-addins, office-store

We have created a Word add-in and successfully published it to AppSource.

When searching AppSource on the web it shows up at the below link:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001491?src=office

But if I try to browse for it within Word by going to Insert -> Add-ins -> Store, and searching for it by name, it is not shown (both in Word 2016 and 365).

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but the published add-in has marketplace availability set to 'United Kingdom' only (however I am based in the United Kingdom so would expect it to appear).

Any ideas why the add-in cannot be searched/found within the store?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Customer Support questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead [here](https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport)
1. Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2. Topic: Offer or App does not show in Marketplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the Office store within Word seems to search for marketplace listings in the United States only.

Inspecting the web requests from Word using Fiddler, the search query has a parameter for `ad=US` by default (I'm not sure if there's anyway to change this from within Word). Attempting the same request but alternating the search query to `ad=GB` correctly brings back the add-in within the results.

The solution was to republish the add-in but include United States in the marketplace availability.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.
That is very useful information and very important for anyone submitting from the UK.